Cannot send a POST request with images (multipart/form) React Native EXPO, Spring as backend
Cannot send a POST request with images (multipart/form) React Native EXPO, Spring as backend
handlePost
const handlePost = async () => {
    const formDataToSend = new FormData();

    const advertisementBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(formData)], {
      type: "application/json",
    });
    formDataToSend.append("advertisement", advertisementBlob);
    imageUris.forEach((img) => {
      const media = {
        uri: img,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: "profile.jpg",
      };
      // const file = new File([blob]);
      formDataToSend.append("files", media);
    });
    try {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(formDataToSend));
      const result = await postAdd(formDataToSend);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

Springs log
2024-07-14 02:10:54 2024-07-13T21:10:54.069Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-3001-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required part 'advertisement' is not present.]

backend:
@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveAdvertisement(@RequestPart("advertisement") AdvertisementDTO aDto,
            @RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> files) {
        return facade.saveAdvertisement(aDto, files);
    }

public ResponseEntity<?> saveAdvertisement(AdvertisementDTO aDto,
            List<MultipartFile> files) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User currentUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Advertisement advertisement = Advertisement.builder()
                .title(aDto.getTitle())
                .description(aDto.getDescription())
                .category(catService.findById(aDto.getCategory().getCategory_id()))
                .user(currentUser)
                .price(aDto.getPrice())
                .date(LocalDateTime.now())
                .views(0L)
                .build();
        String result = iService.validateAndSaveImages(files);
        if (result != null)
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(result);
        advertisement.setImages(files);

        try {
            service.save(advertisement);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\"}");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("Advertisement creation failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

request body
      query: (newAdd) => {
        return {
          url: "/api/secured/create",
          method: "POST",
          body: newAdd,
        };
      },
      invalidatesTags: [{ type: "Advertisements", id: "LIST" }],
    }),

payload JSON:
{
"_parts":
[
  ["advertisement",{"_data":{"blobId":"923737fc-8e5d-43d9-adec-af0fb0ff933d","offset":0,"size":80,"type":"application/json","__collector":{}}}],
  ["files",{"uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FCoreComponent-b964cf2e-b055-4d78-9e16-7ff1dbf5bec4/ImagePicker/83bd2379-6703-4a54-8764-e5427389de54.png","type":"image/jpeg","name":"profile.jpg"}]
]
}

P.S : The fact is web application on React works properly (mostly the same code), but on mobile exaclty when it comes to multipart it does not

please share the request body that is being sent, as well as the controller code that you are calling on the backend

when I said requestBody, I meant literal JSON being sent

Change your postmapping consumes from form-data to application/json

As I understand you can't send a blob file in React Native as we do in React JS, so I gotta add these line of code and this solved the problem :
const createBlob = (data) => {
    return new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: "application/json" });
  };
  const saveBlobToFile = async (blob) => {
    const base64Data = await blobToBase64(blob);
    const fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "advertisement.json";
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(fileUri, base64Data, {
      encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
    });
    return fileUri;
  };

  // Helper function to convert blob to base64
  const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result.split(",")[1]);
      };
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  };

Final result looks like this:
const handlePost = async () => {
    const formDataToSend = new FormData();
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");
    const advertisementBlob = createBlob(formData);
    const advertisementUri = await saveBlobToFile(advertisementBlob);
    formDataToSend.append("advertisement", {
      uri: advertisementUri,
      name: "advertisement.json",
      type: "application/json",
    });

    for (const uri of imageUris) {
      const fileUri = uri.replace("file://", "");
      const fileName = fileUri.split("/").pop();
      const fileType = fileName.endsWith(".png") ? "image/png" : "image/jpeg";
      formDataToSend.append("files", {
        uri: uri,
        type: fileType,
        name: fileName,
      });
    }

    try {
      const result = await axios.post(
        "http://<my_api>:3001/api/secured/create",
        formDataToSend,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          transformRequest: (d) => d,
        }
      );
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.request._response));
    }
  };


